# How to get the values of gates of LSTM using Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to get the values of the three gates of LSTM using keras.

How can I print the `b_i f_i` and `o_i` of the LSTM using keras?

Comment: The gate activations don't seem to be saved on the object instance https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/66c4fdb8937abe725018de7156c5f66f2ec335ed/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1147. You could subclass the LSTM class and override the step method with a copy that has the prints you want - or add the gate activations as attributes.

Comment: I used the 'layer.b_i' but occur 'AttributeError: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'h''

Comment: Do you want the "weights" of these gates or the actual values of the gates? You're aware that the value changes for each iteration in the layer, and you actually have a number of iterations equal to the `timeSteps` input dimension?

Comment: I want to the actual of the gates for each timesetps

Comment: How to subclass the LSTM class and override the step method with a copy that has the prints you want??