# How to print the attribute of b_i,W_i and U_i of the LSTM in keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

How to rewrite the keras/layers/recurrent.py to make the attribute of b_i of LSTM can be used and printed??

```
def step(self, x, states):
    assert len(states) == 2
    h_tm1 = states[0]
    c_tm1 = states[1]

    x_i = K.dot(x, self.W_i) + self.b_i
    x_f = K.dot(x, self.W_f) + self.b_f
    x_c = K.dot(x, self.W_c) + self.b_c
    x_o = K.dot(x, self.W_o) + self.b_o

    i = self.inner_activation(x_i + K.dot(h_tm1, self.U_i))
    f = self.inner_activation(x_f + K.dot(h_tm1, self.U_f))
    c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(h_tm1, self.U_c))
    o = self.inner_activation(x_o + K.dot(h_tm1, self.U_o))
    h = o * self.activation(c)
    return h, [h, c]
```

Comment: `b_i` seems to be a bias. The actual gate values seem to be `x_i` and others. But if you want them with the activations, then it's `i`.  Try `K.print_tensor(b_i,message="optional message")`. -- https://keras.io/backend/#print_tensor

Comment: If you want the weights, you don't need to change the layer, just find it in the model and use `model.layers[i].get_weights()`. You will receive a list, each element will be one of the weights. The exact order must be analysed.

Comment: But I want print the `i`,`f`,`c` and `o`. I need to rewrite the code.

Comment: Have you seen my answer to your other question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156809/how-to-get-the-values-of-gates-of-lstm-using-keras/46159672

Comment: I have seen you answer to my other question and rewrite the step function in the recurrent.py? But it not print the `i` `f` when i built a LSTM. How can i print it when i built them LSTM model? Need I add some code to LSTM?

Comment: There isn't any value when you build a model. Values only exist when you "predict" values or when you "train values". --- Important: that answer tells you how to create your own kind of LSTM without changing the original files! Changing the original files is dangerous.

Comment: Very thanks for you remind.But how can i print the values when i predict the values. This is my LSTM code

Comment: This is my code 
`model = Sequential()
shape = trian_x.shape
model.add(LSTM(1000, input_shape=(shape[1], shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(trian_y.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse')
st =time.time()
model.fit(trian_x, trian_y, batch_size=20, nb_epoch=1, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
print('Evaluate')
score = model.evaluate(trian_x, trian_y, verbose=1)
print('\n   Train',score)
score = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=1)`

Comment: Try to use these in the code you changed:
      `K.print_tensor(i,"this is i")`
      `K.print_tensor(f,"this is f")`
      `K.print_tensor(c,"this is c")`
      `K.print_tensor(o,"this is o")`
      `K.print_tensor(h,"this is h")`
Simply using `model.fit()` should print the values. (I tested, and it seems that my answer in the other question won't work)

Comment: I followed your tips but it seem it not print the `i` when fit the model